# Find the transition function of the process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ a pure death process with Q-matrix:
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&\cdots0\\
k& -k &0&0&\cdots0\\
0&k&-k&0&\cdots 0\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots\\
0&0&\cdots&k&-k 
\end{pmatrix}$$
And state space $S=\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$, find the probabilities $P(X(t)=i)$ for $i=0,1,...,n$ if $X(0)=n.$

Using Chapman-Kolmogorov's equation I have:

$$P_i(t)=\sum_jP(X(0)=j)P_{j,i}(t)=P_{n,i}(t)$$

But the only way that I know for solve that is by the Backward/Forward equations, How can I find the transition functions efficiently?

Comment: The matrix $P (t) $ is $e^{Qt} $. This can be calculated easily given a diagonalization of $Q $. In this case you have a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix so its eigenvalues can be explicitly calculated. I think the eigenvectors can be explicitly calculated too.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N(t)$ be be a Poisson process with rate $k$. Since the death rate is constant, the number of deaths in $(0,t]$ is given by $$n-X(t)=N(t)\wedge n.$$ It follows that $$X(t) = (n-N(t))^+, $$ and so $$\mathbb P(X(t)=j) = \mathbb P((n-N(t))^+=j) =\begin{cases}\mathbb P(N(t)\geqslant n),& j=0\\ \mathbb P(N(t)=n-j),& j=1,\ldots,n\end{cases}
 $$
with 
$$\mathbb P(N(t)=i) = \frac{e^{-kt}(kt)^i}{i!}. $$